# How to open nested structure without name clash in C programming?

Tags: c++, c, naming-conventions, c-preprocessor

I like to open a structure and use member names directly this way:

```
typedef struct{
    int n;
    int m;
    int *A;
    int *B;
    type1 *slave;
} type2;

#define n this->n
#define m this->m
#define A this->A
#define B this->B

void routine2(type2 *this){
    n = slave->n;
    m = n + 1;
    A = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
}
```

Most of times, it works great and my code is easy to read. However, the above code cannot compile since `slave->n` will be expanded by preprocessor to `slave->this->n`. I am looking for suggestions on how to overcome this difficulty. In my understanding, C++ allows one to do this way if the above structure is a class, and `routine2()` is a member function. How can I achieve the same thing in **C**?

Comment: Don't use `this` as a name for a variable. `this` is a reserved keyword in c++. I'd use a smart pointer for A and `free` as custom deleter (`A = std::shared_ptr<int>(malloc(n * sizeof(int)), free);`)

Answer (score 1):

Pick one:

- Don't do that. This is an abuse of the C macro system, and the style is sufficiently out-of-the-ordinary that you will alienate anyone else trying to make sense of your code.
- Use C++. If you find the syntactic sugar provided by C++ for instance member access to be that compelling, then just write your code in C++.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's a very, very dangerous idea to do things like this. It's almost guaranteed to result in hard to find bugs.
2. If you insist, one obvious way is to introduce unique names, like e.g. struct tm does - everything starts with tm_ prefix. Or introduce e.g. CAPITAL_LETTER macros for capital_letter names. But it probably isn't what you want.